# Out of memory in Cassandra on massive inserts

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm trying to insert data with big column values (1-25Mb) and after a couple seconds, one of my nodes dies, either by throwing an OOM or by being stuck in an endless GC loop.

It usually tries to flush CFs, but then it says *Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families*.

Since the log advised me to reduce memtable/cache sizes, I tried to figure out what was using up all this memory in order to adapt my settings, so I ran  `nodetool flush / invalidaterowcache / invalidatekeycache` and then triggered a GC through jconsole.

Unfortunately, my memory usage stayed high (>60%) even though the server is idling.

So, my problem is Why is the server running out of memory when inserting big values? and also, why isn't the server giving some memory back?

#### Edit

I did a heapdump and the heap is full of byte[], mainly referenced by  of `org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummary$KeyPosition`.

I don't understand how this is possible since everything is supposed to have been flushed.

Comment: How is your JVM set up on the Linux box? (Heap size, garbage collection settings, etc.) Also, how do you have Cassandra configured? Are you using secondary indexes on your column families? First place I'd check is to make sure you've got a big enough heap on your linux box. The server won't release the memory because it either has active references to the data (all the stuff you just put in) or you're using the naive stop-world GC that doesn't collect very often and when it does it stops everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated the heap dump with MAT and it turns out that the OutOfMemory happened because a lot of memory was used by Thrift.

Since I had to transfer big chunks of data for my column values, I changed those settings to 128, to "be safe":

- thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb
- thrift_max_message_length_in_mb

But it turns out that Thrift allocates one `byte[2 * thrift_max_message_length_in_mb]` per receiving thread, and I had three of those. So I was using 768Mb just for receive buffers...

Changing the settings to 32 fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you hit the [infamous memory fragmentation](http://www.davidcoombes.co/?p=16) issue. I'm not sure whether Cassandra takes away some of the fragmentation issues, but generally, in .NET and potentially any Windows program, can run into this.

When you select anything above 85000 bytes (yes, odd number, but it's what it is), objects are stored in the Large Object Heap. The LOH gets GC'ed only as generation 2, but worse, it gets *never* compacted. The reason is partly caused by [the way the OS is implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Result: when you store objects of say 2MB, 5MB, 3MB, 2MB, 3MB and objects of 2MB get GC'ed you have potentially 4MB free. But if you then try to create a new object of 3MB, it cannot be placed there because of the fragmentation (2 holes of 2MB) and moves to the top of the heap. Eventually, this runs out of room. So: **there can be enough memory available, but you will get an OOM regardless, due to this fragmentation**.

This issue is mostly seen on 32 bit x86 applications on 64 bit (WOW64) and 32 bit Windows. 64 bit applications also have the fragmentation issue, but since virtual memory is much larger, you first hit paging the memory (becoming real slow) before you hit actual fragmentation issues.

If this is indeed the issue (you can check the fragmentation visually with [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) and with [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx)) you can solve it by creating a large pool of bytes and reuse your own pool, thus preventing fragmentation.

Comment: Unfortunately my issue is on the Cassandra side, so Java / Linux. And furthermore, I just did a heapdump and it's actually full.

Comment: @alprema: the fragmentation is not .NET specific, not even OS specific. If you investigated the heapdump and you didn't find gaps, then Cassandra is actually really out of memory. Cassandra-bug? Have you tried these http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.cassandra.user/22595?